# There is no current event loop in thread 'ThreadPoolExecutor-0_0' while using pulumi_azure_native.authorization

Tags: pulumi, pulumi-azure, pulumi-python

I have a couple of custom provider components in my projects and I've written a function to return the credentials of the current Pulumi login context. Here is my function:

```py
def get_access_token(endpoint: Optional[str] = None) -> Tuple[str, str, str]:
    access_token = authorization.get_client_token(endpoint=endpoint).token
    client_config = authorization.get_client_config()
    tenant_id = client_config.tenant_id
    subscription_id = client_config.subscription_id
    return tenant_id, subscription_id, access_token
```

However, I get the following error during `pulumi up` which is directly caused by the above function:

```
    C:\Workspace\vsts-agent-win-x64-2.191.1\_work\39\s\Infrastructure\venv\lib\site-packages\grpc\_server.py:457: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'invoke.<locals>.do_rpc' was never awaited
      return None, False
    RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback

  pulumi-python:dynamic/keyvault:AccessPolicy (kv-access-policy-pulumi-developer):
    error: Exception calling application: There is no current event loop in thread 'ThreadPoolExecutor-0_0'.

  pulumi-python:dynamic/keyvault:Certificate (kv-certificate-auto-ssl-certificate):
    error: Exception calling application: There is no current event loop in thread 'ThreadPoolExecutor-0_0'.
```

I expected for the `pulumi_azure_native.authorization` methods to work properly as mentioned in their documents. However, somehow, I can't find an easy way to access the current Pulumi login context within my codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `get_client_token` returns an `Awaitable`, I should've made my method (`get_access_token`) an async method and added some `await`s:

```py
async def get_access_token(endpoint: Optional[str] = None) -> Tuple[str, str, str]:
    access_token = (await authorization.get_client_token(endpoint=endpoint)).token
    client_config = await authorization.get_client_config()
    tenant_id = client_config.tenant_id
    subscription_id = client_config.subscription_id
    return tenant_id, subscription_id, access_token
```